# how to run $(this).click() multiple times without losing previous selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Consider the code shown below. I have this function and for which I will pass a table id and a string for the row that I am looking for. When I call the function and if I found that particular string in that table's row, I have one on click event that will be triggered.

This Onclick event will basically select an option from a multi-option dropdown menu.
Now, problem occurs when from same table, if I have multiple entries, it will only select last option and all other options are overwritten. is there any way to fire all onclick event same time or even one by one without losing last selected option.

```
   function reapply_filter(id, str) {
        setTimeout(function(){  
            $("#DataTables_Table_"+id).find("tr").each(function(i, value) {
                var nodeList = $(this).find('.dtsp-name').html();
                if(nodeList == str) {
                    $(this).find("div").click();
                }
            });
            list_filters();
        }, 500);  
    }
```

Practical Explaination:
Consider I have called function 3 times;

```
reapply_filter(1, "Project 10");
reapply_filter(1, "Project 11");
reapply_filter(1, "Project 12");
```

Expected Output:

[image]

What I am getting:

[image]

Consider one more case:

```
reapply_filter(1, "Project 10");
reapply_filter(1, "Project 11");
reapply_filter(1, "Project 12");
reapply_filter(2, "Company 3");
reapply_filter(3, "2021-02-16");
```

Expected output:

[image]

What I am getting is:

[image]

Comment: could you show the html code of your dropdown menu? because following the way you create your dropdown the solution could be different

Comment: actually it is part of  library provided by dataTable, I only know that click event on that particular div will select desired row.

Comment: how you do multiple selection, with ctrl key? or other possibility? an what is the hetml of an option selected in dropdown?

Comment: Yes I use ctrl key for manual selection, but in jquery I am unable to find a way to do so.

Comment: You can refer https://datatables.net/extensions/searchpanes/examples/initialisation/simple.html for overview of table

Comment: why not highlight the selection so instead off clicking by adding the class which highlight the selection? so to do that need to see your hml

Answer (score 0):

Without hml code is difficult to propose a specific solution, so
Read in documentation, Instead to trigger a click, why not add the class `selected` to the right div, the selection wil be highlighted automatically.

```
<tr class = "even selected" >
  <td class = "dtsp-nameColumn sorting_1" >
    <div class = "dtsp-nameCont" >
      <span title = "20" class = "dtsp-name"> 20 </span>
      <span class="dtsp-pill">1</span >
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

if you want abolutely to use click ,another solution will be:
you trigger a click for the first selection, but for next, you trigger ctrl + click.

1. search if class `selected` already exists in the dropdown, in this case trigger a ctrl click like this:

   ```
   $('your selector').trigger($.Event("click", { ctrlKey: true }))
   ```

or

```
var e = jQuery.Event("click");
e.ctrlKey = true;
$('your selector').trigger(e);
```

2. if there is no class which indicates something is selected,  you could use a boolean var for each dropdown which indicates if something is already selected or not..

Comment: tried it earlier, it will only select that row, filter will not be applied.

Comment: to apply the filter, onclick must be triggered, otherwise selection is of no use

Comment: and manually how you do a multiple selection? with ctrl key?

Comment: so i propose you to generate a ctrl click when you have already selected something in the dropdown.. sorry for my english hope you understant what i want to mean

Comment: Yes Sir I get it